# Microsoft dynamics AX 2009 Problems with grid coloring

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2009

So i'm trying to colorize form lines with different colors. if i  check current.PrimaryTransportation  checkbox in one line and all i get is one big yellow grid

the code i'm using looks like this:

```
public void displayOption(Common _record, FormRowDisplayOption _options)
{
    SIS_ResourcesTmp        buffer = _record;
    SIS_ResourceSum         current = SIS_ResourceSum_DS.cursor();

    #define.grey(12895428)
    #define.white(16448250)
    #define.yellow(3927039)
    ;

    _options.backColor(#grey);

    if (!current.VendorPrice && !current.UnitConvertRate) {
        if (!current.UnitConvertToTons && !current.DistanceVendorToObject && current.PrimaryTransportation) {
            _options.backColor(#yellow);
        }
    } else {
       _options.backColor(#white);
    }

    SIS_ResourcesTmp_ds.refresh();
}
```

Comment: AX supports the use of hex literals, so use 0xC4C4C4 instead of 12895428. Colors are GBR encoded.

Answer (score 1):

Use the parameter `_record` to check whether to set the color for the current row to yellow or not.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your scenario but I think you need one more else conditon for the nested if statement. Or I would rather try to eliminate the nested if like this:

```
if (!current.VendPrice && 
    !current.UnitConvertRate && 
    !current.UnitConvertToTons &&
    current.PrimaryTransportation)
{
    _options.backColor(#yellow);
}
else
{
    _options.backColor(#white);
}
```